# Using new keyword/operator in C++

Tags: c++

What is the result of following statement?

```
std::string p;
new (&p) std::string("New word");
```

Does it create a new heap allocation? or does it just replace the static variable ? How does it differ from the following?

```
p = std::string("New word");
p = new std::string("New word");
```

EDIT:
Thanks guys. Yeah it seems it's a placement new.

Comment: The question will make more sense if you post the definition of `p`.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918791/how-to-properly-free-the-memory-allocated-by-placement-new/8918942#8918942

Comment: Might be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13370935/10077, though I'm hesitant to hammer it.

Comment: looks like placement new

Comment: The first code is undefined behaviour (if an object has a destructor that does something, you can't placement-new over the top of it without calling the destructor first). The second one won't compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `new (&p) std::string("New word");` is using **placement new**.  `&p` must point at a pre-existing block of memory that is at least `sizeof(std::string)` bytes in size.  The `std::string` object will be constructed inside that memory, instead of in a newly allocated block of memory.  The object must be destroyed by calling its destructor directly when you are done using it, eg:

  ```
  char buffer[sizeof(std::string)];
  std::string *p = new (buffer) std::string("New word");
  ...
  p->~std::string();
  ```
- `p = std::string("New word");` could be doing different things, depending on the context in which it is used:

  - if used in a variable declaration statement, `p` is allocated on stack (automatic) or heap (dynamic) memory (depending on context) and is copy-constructed using the `std::string` value:

    ```
    some_type p = std::string("New word");
    //
    // same as:
    // some_type p(std::string("New word"));
    //
    // if some_type=std::string, same as:
    // std::string p("New word");
    ...
    ```
  - if used in an assignment statement on a pre-existing object, it is allocating a block of temporary stack (automatic) memory, constructing a new temporary `std::string` object in that memory, assigning that temp object to `p`, and then destroying the temp object and freeing the temp memory.
- `p = new std::string("New word");` is allocating a new block of heap (dynamic) memory, constructing the `std::string` object in that memory, and then assigning the memory address to the `p` pointer.  The object must be destroyed manually using `delete`:

  ```
  std::string *p = new std::string("New word");
  ...
  delete p;
  ```

In all three cases, the `std::string` object contains an internal pointer to its character data, which may point to memory on the stack (automatic) or heap (dynamic), depending on where the `std::string` is allocated, what optimizations it employs, etc.

Comment: What about `p = std::string("New word");` that isn't initializing a new variable?

Comment: The only way that can compile is if `p` is an actual `std::string` object (or an object with a `operator=` that accepts `std::string` as input), not a `std::string*` pointer to an object.

Comment: That's what I'm asking about, e.g. `std::string p; ...; p = std::string("New word");`. Does this make a temporary string and copy it, or does copy elision bypass that?

Comment: In your first example it may fail due to the char buffer not being aligned for std::string  (this is what `std::aligned_storage` is for)

Comment: @Barmar: `std::string p; ...; p = std::string("New word");` is actually  `std::string p; ...; p.operator=(std::string("New word"));`  It is constructing a temp object and passing it to `p`, which then copies the data.

Comment: Does copy elision allow it to avoid the temporary?

Comment: @Barmar: `p = std::string("New word")` is explicitly constructing a temp `std::string` object, which will then get passed to `std::string::operator=(const std::string&)` (or `std:string::operator=(std::string&&)` in C++11). Copy elision cannot avoid that temp, since it is needed to satisfy the input parameter of `operator=`. If you remove the explicit construction (use `p = "New word"` instead) then the compiler will call `std::string::operator=(const char*)` instead, and avoid making any temps at all.